# deleteNode function appears to break connection list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm attempting to build a customer list class that simulates a service center. My deleteNode function will only correctly delete the head of the list without breaking the links.

I've tried drawing diagrams of the linked list and tracing the program by hand, but on paper, it appears correct to me. The problem seems to be somewhere in the else statement, but I cannot pinpoint where.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class CustomerList
{
private:

    // structure to represent customer as a node
    struct CustomerNode
    {
        unsigned int sequence_number{};
        string name{}, service_required{};
        int month{}, day{}, year{}, hour{}, minute{};
        struct CustomerNode* next_node{ nullptr };
    };

    // Pointers to first and last node in the linked list
    CustomerNode* head;
    CustomerNode* last_node;

public:


    CustomerList();

    // Class member functions
    void insertNode(string, string, int, int, int, int, int);
    void deleteNode(string);
    void serveCustomer();
    void listAll();

    ~CustomerList();


};
```

```
void CustomerList::deleteNode(string name)
{
    CustomerNode* node_ptr;
    CustomerNode* previous_node;

    if (!head)
    {
        cout << "The list is empty." << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (head->name == name)
    {
        node_ptr = head->next_node;
        delete head;
        head = node_ptr;
    }

    else
    {
        node_ptr = head;

        while (node_ptr != nullptr && node_ptr->name != name)
        {
            previous_node = node_ptr;
            node_ptr = node_ptr->next_node;

        }


        if (node_ptr)
        {
            previous_node = node_ptr->next_node;
            delete node_ptr;
        }       

    }
}
```

If I have multiple nodes, and delete a node, only that node should be deleted. The next_node pointer in the struct should point to the node after the node that was deleted. Instead, when I display the nodes in the linked list any node after the head appears to point to garbage data.

Comment: Since the problem is that garbage data is shown where the node was deleted, consider your code that handles fixing up node pointers to remove the node you are deleting.  Does `previous_node = node_ptr->next_node;` do what you need it to do?

Comment: Looks to me `previous_node = node_ptr->next_node;` should be `previous_node->next_node = node_ptr->next_node;`

Comment: The best way I know of to debug linked lists is to draw pictures. Draw the list. Then, following your coded instructions exactly, draw each step of the removal. When you find yourself drawing something silly, congratulations! You found the bug AND you probably have a good idea of what you needed to do instead.

Comment: As far as I can tell, on paper previous_node = node_ptr->next_node, does what I need it to do. Drawing it out, I haven't found any issues with the way it should work. However, when I run the program it clearly breaks at the deleted node, UNLESS the node is the head node. If I have 6 nodes and delete the 4th node, the connection with node 5 and 6 are broken and junk data is displayed. Also, I've tried previous_node->next_node = node_ptr->next_node, but this breaks the program, and will not run at all.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Richard Chambers is right. You need to set the "next_node" of the "previous_node" instead of "previous_node".
    `if (node_ptr)
     {
        previous_node->next_node = node_ptr->next_node;
        delete node_ptr;
     }`

Comment: Making that change causes a build error. The program will not start. I get a warning that says "C6001 using uninitialized memore 'previous_node'.".

Comment: Is it a compiling error or warning? If it is a warning, you can ignore it. You may need to configure your compiler to ignore warnings.

Comment: It's just a warning. However, the program will not run once that change is made. If I hit ctrl + F5, a box will pop up that says "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?"

Comment: This is being ran in microsoft visual studios community. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you sure you have not any other error which can prevent a successful build?

Comment: You can suppress specific warnings for C++, see this link:(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2019)